# How to draw arrow between two text lines?

Tags: arrows, xy-pic

I want to draw this figure. Is it possible ?
[image]

I have written the following code to draw that figure :

```
    \documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{xypic,wrapfig}
\begin{document}


\xymatrix{  
\verb|\begin{wrapfigure}|[12]{r}[34pt]{5cm} &  <figure> &  \verb|\end{wrapfigure}|\\


 & [<Number of narrow lines>]{<placement>}[<overhang>]{<width>}&
}

\end{document}
```

But failed!

---

@Gonzalo Medina's answer which I have compiled it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner ysep=4pt] (#1) {};}

\def\n#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small#1}}
\def\cs#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\\#1}}
\def\all{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\{}}
\def\cll{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\}}}
\def\aop#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\[#1\char`\]}}
\def\aob#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\{#1\char`\}}}
\def\gr#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small<\,#1\,>}}
\def\env#1{\all\n{#1}\cll}

\begin{document}

\hfill\cs{begin}\env{wrapfigure}\aop{\tikzmark{nla}12}%
\aob{\tikzmark{pla}r}\aop{\tikzmark{ova}34pt}\aob{\tikzmark{wia}5cm} %
\gr{figure} \cs{end}\env{wrapfigure}

\vskip20pt

\noindent\aop{\gr{number of \tikzmark{nlb}narrow lines}}%
\aob{\gr{\tikzmark{plb}placement}}\aop{\gr{\tikzmark{ovb}overhang}}%
\aob{\gr{\tikzmark{wib}width}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] ([xshift=15pt,yshift=3pt]nlb.north) -- ([xshift=5pt]nla.south);
\draw[->] ([xshift=15pt,yshift=3pt]plb.north) -- (pla.south);
\draw[->] ([xshift=15pt,yshift=3pt]ovb.north) -- ([xshift=8pt]ova.south);
\draw[->] ([xshift=15pt,yshift=3pt]wib.north) -- ([xshift=8pt]wia.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But This gives:

[image]

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You need to compile three times for the code to produce the lines in the right position.

Answer (score 11):

One option would be to use the ubiquituous `\tikzmark` command to place some marks, and then use the marks to draw the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner ysep=4pt] (#1) {};}

\def\n#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small#1}}
\def\cs#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\\#1}}
\def\all{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\{}}
\def\cll{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\}}}
\def\aop#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\[#1\char`\]}}
\def\aob#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small\char`\{#1\char`\}}}
\def\gr#1{{\normalfont\ttfamily\small<\,#1\,>}}
\def\env#1{\all\n{#1}\cll}

\begin{document}

\hfill\cs{begin}\env{wrapfigure}\aop{\tikzmark{nla}12}%
\aob{\tikzmark{pla}r}\aop{\tikzmark{ova}34pt}\aob{\tikzmark{wia}5cm} %
\gr{figure} \cs{end}\env{wrapfigure}

\vskip20pt

\noindent\aop{\gr{number of \tikzmark{nlb}narrow lines}}%
\aob{\gr{\tikzmark{plb}placement}}\aop{\gr{\tikzmark{ovb}overhang}}%
\aob{\gr{\tikzmark{wib}width}}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] ([xshift=15pt,yshift=3pt]nlb.north) -- ([xshift=5pt]nla.south);
\draw[->] ([xshift=15pt,yshift=3pt]plb.north) -- (pla.south);
\draw[->] ([xshift=15pt,yshift=3pt]ovb.north) -- ([xshift=8pt]ova.south);
\draw[->] ([xshift=15pt,yshift=3pt]wib.north) -- ([xshift=8pt]wia.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The commands `\n`, `\cs`, `\all`,...,`\env` were defined to facilitate the writing of code-like syntax, without using `\verb`.

The above code needs at least two runs to stabilize.

In my personal opinion, there's no need to use those arrows, I'd rather use something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
\begin{wrapfigure}[<narrow lines>]{<placement>}[<overhang>]{<width>}
(figure code)
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{lstlisting}
Where \lstinline{<narrow lines>} must be a positive integer,...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your first answer does not give the picture you have post.I have compiled it and this gives which shown in the following answer.

Comment: @SoumitraSen sorry to bother you, but I noticed that although you have up-voted answers, you still haven't accepted any of them. Accepting and up-voting are two different actions: you can up-vote several answers to a question (the ones you consider good), but you can only accept one answer per question, using the check-mark to the left of the answer. Please consider revising your questions and accepting the answers that you consider best solved your problems. In case of doubt, please see [`How do you accept an answer?`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).